# Dynamically loading User Control in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a `UserControl.ascx` which essentially outputs the Name and Email of the user currently logged in (stored in session variables, for the record) at the top of every page on my website. Said control is currently called by `Site.Master` using `<%Html.RenderPartial("UserControl")%>`.

It works fine when I log in for the first time and my details are displayed correctly, but when I log out and try to log in again something strange happens...

The Control itself tests the condition `Session("auth")`, which my controller sets to `true` upon authenticating a user and which it forces to `false` when the logout button is pressed. All session variables are cleared upon logging out.

(For the record, my user control used to check `Request.IsAuthenticated` rather than `Session("auth")` to determine the current Session State. The same issue arised.)

The problem is that when I try to log in as a different user, instead of showing the new user's information in the header, nothing appears beside Name: and Email: (see code below). I suspect this is because `UserControl.ascx` is not updating its state.

Ideally, I'd like a solution which would force UserControl to check Session variables every time a page is loaded. Is there a clean way to achieve this?

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup = "false" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<%-- The following line works around an ASP.NET compiler warning --%>
<%: ""%>
<%
    If Session("auth") Then
    %>
        Name: <b><%: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("user")%></b>
        [ <%: Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account")%> ]<br />
        Email: <b><%: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("email") %></b>
    <%
    Else
    %>
        Name: <b>Not logged in</b>
        [ <%: Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account")%> ]<br />
        Email: <b>Not logged in</b>
    <%        
    End If  
%>
```

Here's the code from my controller which handles form submission on the login page:

```
<HttpPost()> _
    Public Function LogOn(ByVal model As LogOnModel, ByVal returnUrl As String) As ActionResult
        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            If MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password) Then
                FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName)
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) Then
                    Return Redirect(returnUrl)
                Else
                    Session("auth") = True
                    Session("user") = model.UserName
                    Session("email") = MembershipService.GetEmail(model.UserName, model.Password)
                    Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")
                End If
            Else
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.")
            End If
        End If

        ' If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        Return View(model)
    End Function
```

Comment: If you're resetting your session variables on log in, they should be current - unless you're doing explicit caching on your user control.  Could you post the code you're using in the User control?

Comment: Should I post the section from Site.Master which references this control as well? Thanks for the quick reply by the way!

Comment: I believe it's more important checking what you do when you login inside the controller (or when you set the Session vars)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Session("auth")` is of type object. You need to check null and cast to type bool in your if statement. Otherwise you are just checking if there is an object in the session, whether it's true or false. This explains why it works the first time and not the second.

```
Dim isAuth As Boolean
Dim auth As String = TryCast(Session("auth"), String)
If Boolean.TryParse(auth, isAuth) AndAlso isAuth Then
   ' logged in
Else
   ' not logged in
End If
```

Comment: I just gave this snippet a try, but now the control believes I am logged out even though my credentials worked (i.e. Name: Not logged in, Email: Not logged in). I can navigate the site freely despite web.config limiting viewing to authenticated users, meaning UserControl is the only unit of the site that hasn't recognized authentication yet. I'll post the controller in just a moment though.

Comment: Is the logic just inverted? You may just need to step through in debugger and see what's going on in that if statement, and what IsAuthenticated is set to.

Comment: Also in your controller, if there's a return URL you are never setting the session variable.

Comment: Inverting the condition statement shows "Not logged in" when I log in the first time, null (well, nothing appears) when I log out, and null again when I log in a second time. This is merely the identical result of previous executions, just with the output messages swapped. The logic does appear to be correct.

Comment: That's interesting, I think we're almost at the solution. However, the session variables are set in the first login. Do you mean the return URL is preventing session clearing in Logout? EDIT: Unless you're referring to `Return Redirect(returnUrl)`, though the only time I enter that loop is if one of my credentials is missing, which isn't the case here.

Comment: I'm referring to `If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)`

Comment: Brilliant, it worked! I simply nuked those two lines (I'm not sure why I even had them there, though I suspect it came with the default MVC Application project template in VS2010). Thank you very much for your help!